# Making Sidebar with bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

I wanna make sidebar like this http://dota2.cyborgmatt.com/prizetracker/dotapits3

but couldn't do it. Everytime I tried and failed. You can click to sidebar text and it can open to you at right side section.

I'm new kinda things thank you.

Comment: maybe post in some sample code, with what you tried, or maybe a code snippet, or a jsfiddle, so people can help you out based on that, a 'make this for me' question is never a good idea

Answer (score 1):

I created a sidebar for bootstrap, because i didn't find what i searched for on internet, here's the code

**CSS**

```css
#wrapper {
    margin-left: 200px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    background: #555;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .logo {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked li {

}

#sidebar-wrapper .nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked li a {
    color: #FFF;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked li a:hover {
    background: #333;
}



**HTML**
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
        LOGO
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Produits</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Réservations</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Commandes</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Messages</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's an example of the result in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ZvsnP5vpzx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using Bootstrap you can use the baked in components. Take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav and you are ready to go. Also you can analyze the code used in your example and look up how it's done. It's pretty straightforward.

EDIT: I fiddled something: http://jsfiddle.net/Ltyuxy7h/6/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <ul class="nav>
            <li><a href="#">Testlink</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Testlink</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Testlink</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Testlink</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Testlink</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Testlink</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
</div>
```